# clear map of vector pointer in c++

Tags: c++, oop, dictionary

```
map<string ,vector<void*>> mymap;
```

I tried like,

```
std::map<std::string, vector<void*>>::iterator itr = mymap.begin();

std::vector<void*> ::iterator it =(itr->second).begin();


if(it != (itr->second).end())
{
    (itr->second).resize(0);
    (itr->second).shrink_to_fit();
}


mymap.clear();
```

Comment: `vector<void*>`?  Why?  Also, what does `std::map` have to do with this, when the issue is solely with `std::vector`?

Comment: Er, why do you think `mymap.clear()` doesn't clear your map ?

Comment: @hurkyl :: it's clearing value ., but map holding some address

Comment: map will key will still point to an empty vector even after you clear the vector.  You don't want an empty vector?

Comment: for mymap.clear() vector got empty . i want that pointing to empty vector will hold some address to be cleared

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you edit your question to include what you want?

Comment: @Kuppusamy: For `mymap.clear()`, all of the contained vectors got *destroyed*; there are none left.

Comment: @Kuppusamyk The map's data type is `std::vector<void*>`, not a `std::vector<void*>*` (a pointer to a vector).  So there is no pointer to delete.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question, but if you meant that you want to delete the objects pointed by `vector<void*>`, then use:

```
for (const auto& v : mymap) //for each value in the map
    for (const auto& address: v.second) //for each element in the vector
        delete address;
mymap.clear ();
```

Comment: @ Mattia F. - or `delete [] address`, instead of `free(address)`, if `address` was allocated with `new []`

Comment: Well, I posted just an example, he can do whatever he wants with that value.